# Code-generated input in Google Chrome DevTools Console

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to read card data using MagTek card reader through MagTek Web API. The code which is used for this

```
...
function doRequest(url, data, timeout, success, handleError) {
    var request = {
        url: HTTP_HOST + path,
        method: method,
        data: data,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
            'Cache-Control': 'no-cache'
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: success,
        timeout: timeout,
        error: handleError
    };
    $.ajax(request);
}
...


function extractCardDataFromResponse(response) {
    var data = response.CardSwipeOutput;
    var names = data.CardName.split('/');
    return {
        cardNumber: data.Track2Masked.split('=')[0].substr(1),
        lastName: names[0],
        firstName: names[1],
        expirationMonth: data.CardExpDate.substr(-2),
        expirationYear: '20' + data.CardExpDate.substr(0, 2),
        track2: data.Track2,
        dukptksn: data.KSN
    };
}

function readCard(handlerCardData, onReady, onError) {
    try {
        ...
        onReady();
        ...
        doPost('/RequestCardSwipe', requestBody, 300000, function (response) {
            if (response.CardSwipeOutput.TrackDecodeStatus === '000000') {
                handlerCardData(extractCardDataFromResponse(response));
            }
        }, onError);
    } catch (e) {
        onError(e);
    }
}
```

I run `readCard((a)=>console.log(a), ()=>console.log('ready'), (e)=> {console.log('error');console.log(e);})` in Chrome Developers Console.
After swipe the card data is inserted into console. Why such thing may happen?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MagTek's card readers can be set to one of two modes, HID mode, or KB Emulation mode. In my case card reader was in Key board Emulation mode and card data was inserted to Chrome console. When I set reader to HID mode it started working.